# javascript, turn string into code?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

First question, might be dumb, be easy on me.

So I have an object creator followed by a set of variables, a-z, which create 26 objects with names a-z. I have a piece of code which generates a random letter from a-z and i would like to display a property of the  randomly picked object, but the letter is generated as a string, and `"a".type` comes out as undefined (understandably). so i need to take that string, and remove the quotes from it basically so i can use it. i found somewhere on here someone said `("a").charAt(0)` would work but it doesn't in my case. heres a very simplified version of the code

```
function Object(type) {
    this.type = type;
};

var a = new Object("annoying");

var random = "a";

console.log((random).type);
```

I just want it to log `"annoying"` but i believe that `chance.character` is making it log `"a".type` instead of `a.type`. So i need a way to turn the string ito a usable piece of code so i can refer to the variable.

Comment: First of all, please don't overwrite the global `Object` function.

Comment: "*a set of variables*" - there's your mistake. Make that an array or an object which you can access by property name.

Comment: I DIDNT I PROMISE. I was just trying to put this larger piece of code in a quick example and did it here.

Comment: that s a big chunk of something i borrowed to generate a random lowercase letter. i didnt want to post it as its irrelevant. the main thing is that if it returns `"a"` the thing sent to console log should be `a.type` and i think the problem is that it sends`"a".type`

Comment: as shown, `console.log(window[random].type)`

Comment: ive edited it to make my point more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you should be able to store your objects by their corresponding letter (as a key) in a containing object like so:

```
var letterObjects = {};

function letterObject(type) {
    this.type = type;
};

letterObjects["a"] = new letterObject("annoying");

var random = (chance.character);

console.log(letterObjects[random].type); //annoying
```